# Can't install Aptana on Eclipse 4

Tags: eclipse, aptana

Have a problem with installation of Aptana plugin on Eclipse 4.3,
during installation get errors with System Base:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.2.2.201208200959-7C7C37EAEI9YFMKNDc1bIClwcOi- (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group 3.2.2.201208200959-7C7C37EAEI9YFMKNDc1bIClwcOi-)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse SDK 4.3.0.I20121031-2000 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 4.3.0.I20121031-2000)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Help System Base 3.6.2.v201202080800 (org.eclipse.help.base 3.6.2.v201202080800)
    Help System Base 4.0.0.v201208101300 (org.eclipse.help.base 4.0.0.v201208101300)
    Help System Base 4.0.0.v201210312000 (org.eclipse.help.base 4.0.0.v201210312000)
    Help System Base 4.0.0.v201209201300 (org.eclipse.help.base 4.0.0.v201209201300)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Documentation 3.0.0.1331667762 (com.aptana.documentation 3.0.0.1331667762)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.help.base [3.2.0,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 Core 3.2.2.1345235597-BO7Q8OBea8yJfxywU1DC44EXt-3C (com.aptana.feature.feature.group 3.2.2.1345235597-BO7Q8OBea8yJfxywU1DC44EXt-3C)
    To: com.aptana.documentation [3.0.0.1331667762]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.2.2.201208200959-7C7C37EAEI9YFMKNDc1bIClwcOi- (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group 3.2.2.201208200959-7C7C37EAEI9YFMKNDc1bIClwcOi-)
    To: com.aptana.feature.feature.group [3.2.2.1345235597-BO7Q8OBea8yJfxywU1DC44EXt-3C]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Help System 2.0.0.v20120727-171144-8T7WFLIFK_Qj4LnjFXTwRVDHN (org.eclipse.help.feature.group 2.0.0.v20120727-171144-8T7WFLIFK_Qj4LnjFXTwRVDHN)
    To: org.eclipse.help.base [4.0.0.v201210312000]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Project SDK 4.3.0.v20120906-193403-7V7p-DQ12z-i0bQMG5kbcW605KLL_o-QUPwPOfmX_vkMz (org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group 4.3.0.v20120906-193403-7V7p-DQ12z-i0bQMG5kbcW605KLL_o-QUPwPOfmX_vkMz)
    To: org.eclipse.help.feature.group [2.0.0.v20120727-171144-8T7WFLIFK_Qj4LnjFXTwRVDHN]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse SDK 4.3.0.I20121031-2000 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 4.3.0.I20121031-2000)
    To: org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group [4.3.0.v20120906-193403-7V7p-DQ12z-i0bQMG5kbcW605KLL_o-QUPwPOfmX_vkMz]
```

Comment: Do you have a fresh Eclise version?

Comment: Yep, 4.3.0 and there are nothing to update.

Comment: Hmm you could use the Aptana Studio with Eclipse integrated. But i test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded a fresh version of **Eclipse Classic 4.2.1 32bit** from the Eclipse (last version at the moment) site and this is working well. So i think there is a version problem with **4.3** and the Aptana sources (dependencies) are not set to **Eclipse 4.3**.

**Edit:** With the newest Java 7 version.

Comment: Yes 4.2 is the last stable release. And the dependencies from Aptana are set to this version.